# Linq - Sort list of objects by several contained properties

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

*** Resolved - Ticket updated at bottom ***

I have a list of "line" objects, each with a "StartPoint" and an "EndPoint" property.  Those properties contain standard point objects, each with an "X", "Y", and "Z" component.

Using Linq, I'm trying to sort my list first by ascending minimum Y value of either end point, then by ascending minimum X value of either endpoint (when the Y values match).

I thought the following would work:

```
var sortedList = linesList
    .OrderBy(o => Math.Min(o.StartPoint.Y, o.EndPoint.Y))
    .ThenBy(o => Math.Min(o.StartPoint.X, o.EndPoint.X));

foreach (Line thisLine in sortedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(thisLine.StartPoint + ", " + thisLine.EndPoint);
}
```

However, that produces this order (written as xs, ys, zs, xe, ye, ze):

```
737.928, 825.293, 0, 737.928, 826.293, 0
737.616, 825.293, 0, 737.616, 826.293, 0
733.928, 825.293, 0, 733.928, 826.293, 0
733.616, 825.293, 0, 733.616, 826.293, 0
729.928, 825.293, 0, 729.928, 826.293, 0
729.616, 825.293, 0, 729.616, 826.293, 0
725.928, 825.293, 0, 725.928, 826.293, 0
725.616, 825.293, 0, 725.616, 826.293, 0
721.928, 825.293, 0, 721.928, 826.293, 0
721.616, 825.293, 0, 721.616, 826.293, 0
717.928, 825.293, 0, 717.928, 826.293, 0
717.616, 825.293, 0, 717.616, 826.293, 0
713.928, 825.293, 0, 713.928, 826.293, 0
713.616, 825.293, 0, 713.616, 826.293, 0
709.928, 825.293, 0, 709.928, 826.293, 0
709.616, 825.293, 0, 709.616, 826.293, 0
705.928, 825.293, 0, 705.928, 826.293, 0
705.616, 825.293, 0, 705.616, 826.293, 0
701.928, 825.293, 0, 701.928, 826.293, 0
701.616, 825.293, 0, 701.616, 826.293, 0
697.928, 825.293, 0, 697.928, 826.293, 0
697.616, 825.293, 0, 697.616, 826.293, 0
693.928, 825.293, 0, 693.928, 826.293, 0
693.616, 825.293, 0, 693.616, 826.293, 0
689.928, 825.293, 0, 689.928, 826.293, 0
689.616, 825.293, 0, 689.616, 826.293, 0
685.928, 825.293, 0, 685.928, 826.293, 0
685.616, 825.293, 0, 685.616, 826.293, 0
681.928, 825.293, 0, 681.928, 826.293, 0
681.616, 825.293, 0, 681.616, 826.293, 0
677.928, 825.293, 0, 677.928, 826.293, 0
677.616, 825.293, 0, 677.616, 826.293, 0
673.928, 825.293, 0, 673.928, 826.293, 0
673.616, 825.293, 0, 673.616, 826.293, 0
669.928, 825.293, 0, 669.928, 826.293, 0
669.616, 825.293, 0, 669.616, 826.293, 0
737.928, 826.481, 0, 737.928, 827.481, 0
737.616, 826.481, 0, 737.616, 827.481, 0
733.928, 826.481, 0, 733.928, 827.481, 0
733.616, 826.481, 0, 733.616, 827.481, 0
729.928, 826.481, 0, 729.928, 827.481, 0
729.616, 826.481, 0, 729.616, 827.481, 0
.
.
.
```

As you can see, the "Y" values are ascending properly, but the "X" values are descending.

*** UPDATE ****

In the comments section,the possibility of typical float tolerance issues in the OrderBy comparer was raised.  As a quick test, I changed the .OrderBy clause to this:

.OrderBy(o => Math.Min(Math.Round(o.StartPoint.Y, 3), Math.Round(o.EndPoint.Y, 3)))

It's ugly, but it fixed the sort issue. Apparently, none of the "Y" values were being seen as equal. Now that I've forced them to round to 3 places, the values really *do* match and the ThenBy clause is executed to sort by "X" value.

Now, what's a better way to force the match?  Write my own comparer?

Comment: Can you show this in a short but complete program? Are you sure there isn't some negation going on in the X value somewhere?

Comment: Please provide the name and origin of the class representing the type of the StartPoint and EndPoint properties. Was it written by you, some dude from the Internet or by Microsoft ? In case you have the source code, please provide the ToString method and also look at it yourself. Is the order of X, Y and Z respected by the ToString method ? If you don't have the sources, then have you read the documentation of the library surrounding the class and its entourage ?

Comment: Jon,

Thanks for the response, but I'm not sure what you're asking (negation in the X value).  Short of actually creating the list of "line" objects prior to the posted code, that's really about all there is to the problem at hand.  I can sort the list and print it out using exactly the code I posted and get the results shown.

Comment: @JeffGodfrey could you try using `decimal` for your `X` and `Y` in `Line` class instead of the current used type?

Comment: @Eduard - The library that provides both the "Line" object and the "Point3D" object is a 3rd party, commercial CAD library.  I do not have the source in this case.  Though I'm relatively confident that Point3D.ToString() maintains proper X, Y, Z order, I'll certainly verify that.

Comment: This is just a collection of instances of a class with three PointF properties?

Comment: PS have you tried forcing ascending?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - This is a collection of "Line" objects (from a 3rd party CAD library), which, among other things, have 2 Point3D objects for end points.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is the comparison between for example `825.293` is not equal, although it's a little strange, it depends on how you import each line for your list. To be sure, try this `linesList.GroupBy(line=>line.StartPoint.X,(key,g)=>g.First());` to see if there is any line with duplicated `StartPoint.X`?

Comment: This can be due to rounding in the ToString()-method. Perhaps the numbers that seem equal (such as all the 825.293) are not equal, so the ThenBy method is never invoked.

Comment: Are you printing the correct data.  If this is a line why are all the start points and end points the same?  That would be a short line...

Comment: Tolerances - good thought guys (King King and lightbricko).  I'll look into it.

Comment: @Harrison - The end points aren't the same - the "Y" values differ by 1.

Comment: Tolerances!  That's a winner.  Updating the ticket body with new findings...

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the updated question:

If you want to perform custom comparison to order based on rounded values without modifying the actual values, you can implement [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx). Then use the [overload of `OrderBy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) that takes an IComparer.

```
public class NonExactLineComparer : IComparer<Line>
{
    public int Compare(Line x, Line y)
    {
        // Comparison logic
    }
}
```